# How to change the text style from bold to normal

Tags: java, android

I am able to change the text from normal to bold, but I am unable to change from bold to normal. I don't know what I am missing.

```
 boldtext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sStart = bodyText.getSelectionStart();
            sEnd = bodyText.getSelectionEnd();
            Spannable s = bodyText.getText();
            if (bodyText.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.NORMAL ) {
                s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), sStart, sEnd, 0);
                isBold = true;
            }
            else {
                for (CharacterStyle span : s.getSpans(sStart, sEnd, CharacterStyle.class)) {
                    if (span instanceof StyleSpan && ((StyleSpan)span).getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD)
                        s.removeSpan(span);
                         isBold = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: did it not goes to else part ?

Comment: only go to the if part again and again even if text is bold

Comment: I think so its something with bodyText but can't figure it out how to set s.getTypeface()?

Comment: what is the difference between boldtext and bodyText ?

Comment: according to the code, you will need to click the text view again to remove the bold. Did you try to use an on focus change listener and remove the focus when the text view loses focus?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `TextView.getTypeface().getStyle()` and `StyleSpan.getStyle()` do not *always* share the same style. And as expected, your `bodyText.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.NORMAL` is always true because you are setting bold span on partial text, not on the `TextView`.

Instead, you could try with a different comparison, say:

```
Spannable s = bodyText.getText();
StyleSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(sStart, sEnd, StyleSpan.class)
if (spans.length == 0) {
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), sStart, sEnd, SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
} else {
    for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
        s.remove(span);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this would set the whole text to bold/normal. It appears that he only wants to change selected part of the text.

Comment: @Ridcully Thanks for your comment, I've updated my answer.

Comment: why you giving this condition to if (spans.size == 0)?? I don't need this condition. This only works when I don't select the text at all. I need to select the text and then hit the bold button to bold and unbold the text.

Comment: `s.spans(sStart, sEnd, StyleSpan.class)` will find and return an array of `StyleSpan` within your text selection, and assume if your text has bold and normal styles only, then `spans.size == 0` will tell you your text selection contains no bold text, so you can safely set the whole range of text to bold, otherwise remove all the bold spans. Or does it not make sense?

Answer (score 0):

you can try and remove spans using below code.

```
CharacterStyle[] toBeRemovedSpans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(),
                                                MetricAffectingSpan.class);
    for (int index = 0; index < toBeRemovedSpans.length; index++)
        s.removeSpan(toBeRemovedSpans[index]);
    }
```

Comment: My given question code is working but the problem is in the " if (bodyText.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.NORMAL ) " condition. Every time it enters the if condition even if the text is bold. I need to change this statement inside if condition from bodyText to Spannable s but I don't know how to give this same statement for the Spannable text inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void _removeSpansInRange(Spannable text, StylingType type, int selStart, int selEnd) {
    for (Object span : text.getSpans(selStart, selEnd, Object.class)) {
        if (type.matches(span)) {
            int spanStart = text.getSpanStart(span);
            int spanEnd = text.getSpanEnd(span);
            int spanFlags = text.getSpanFlags(span);
            if (spanStart < selStart && selEnd < spanEnd) {
                text.setSpan(span, spanStart, selStart, spanFlags);
                if (StylingType.isSpecific(type)) {
                    text.setSpan(type.newInstance(span), selEnd, spanEnd, 34);
                }
            } else if (spanStart < selStart) {
                text.setSpan(span, spanStart, selStart, spanFlags);
            } else if (spanEnd > selEnd) {
                text.setSpan(span, selEnd, spanEnd, spanFlags);
            } else {
                text.removeSpan(span);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here, text = Yout edittext text,

---

type = Your Bold typface,

---

seleStart = selection start of your edittext,

---

selEnd = selection end of your edittext

Comment: will this work under button click? under button action, it is not recognizing the edit text and type.

Comment: first check if edittext has selection or not and yes it will work under button click.