# Android - Make EditText Normal again after setting Bold / Italic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-typeface

I want an EditText that should make the Text that the user will type to Bold / Italic / Underline / Strike-through on the Button Click. I am able to set the Bold / Italic / Underline / Strike-through by using :

```
 StyleSpan(TypeFace.BOLD)
 StyleSpan(TypeFace.ITALIC)
 StyleSpan(UnderlineSpan())
 StyleSpan(StrikethroughSpan())
```

respectively. But, when I click the normal button, I want the EditText to make the StyleSpan normal again. I have used the `StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)` to make it Normal on button click. But its not working.

So, suppose I apply Bold option and then the Italic Option, It should make the text that will be typed to Bold and Italic. This is working as expected :
[image: Bold and Italic are setting future text to Bold and Italic]

Now, once I unpress the Bold and Italic Button and Press Normal Button again, I expect it to make the text Normal again as I have set `StyleSpan(TypeFace.NORMAL)` in the on click of Normal button.

But, It is not working as you can see :
[image: EditText not becoming normal again]

Code :

```
 private fun initiateFormatting(
    isBold : Boolean = false,
    isItalic : Boolean = false,
    typefaceCode: StyleSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
    isUnderlineSpan: Boolean = false,
    isStrikeThroughSpan: Boolean = false,
    isNormal : Boolean = false
) {
    val startLength = mEditTextNoteContent.length()
    mEditTextNoteContent.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            if(startLength < mEditTextNoteContent.length()) {
                when {
                    isUnderlineSpan -> mEditTextNoteContent.text.setSpan(
                        UnderlineSpan(),
                        startLength,
                        mEditTextNoteContent.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
                    )
                    isStrikeThroughSpan -> mEditTextNoteContent.text.setSpan(
                        StrikethroughSpan(),
                        startLength,
                        mEditTextNoteContent.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
                    )
                    isNormal -> removeSpan(startLength)
                    isBold || isItalic -> {
                        mEditTextNoteContent.text.setSpan(
                            typefaceCode,
                            startLength,
                            mEditTextNoteContent.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    Log.d("Called", "" + typefaceCode.style)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            count: Int, after: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            before: Int, count: Int
        ) {

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method, in this you are passing null in first argument to reset previous properties

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Comment: This makes everything Normal and not the text that will be typed.

Comment: Sorry did not get you, "Makes everything normal"?

Comment: Suppose I have this text in Bold and I press the Normal Button so that the text that will be typed now should be Normal (that is Non Bold). TypeFace.NORMAL will make the above Bold Text Normal along with what will be typed next.

Comment: ok so you want to make the text in different styles, for the same edittext, for that you need to  use extra handling of spannablebuilder where you pass start index of text and end of of text in the same edittext, and the style you want to apply for that particular part  You can google about it

Comment: I have done the same. As I said in the question itself I am able to do all of it, except for setting the text to Normal again.

Comment: seems like something is missed in the code, can you post your relevant code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211707/discussion-between-harikrishnan-vk-and-akashzincle).

Answer (score 0):

StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL) does not work. You can do it like the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038185/how-to-change-the-text-style-from-bold-to-normal). There all StyleSpans are checked and can be deleted.

```
Spannable s = bodyText.getText();
StyleSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(sStart, sEnd, StyleSpan.class);
final StyleSpan bold = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
if (spans.length == 0) {
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), sStart, sEnd, SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
} else {
    for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
       if (span.getStyle() = bold.getStyle()){
           s.remove(span);
       }
    }
}
```